# @graphql-eslint/eslint-plugin errors

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, eslint, graphql-js

We are developing micro-services in NestJS-typescript, Each of them exposes a GraphQL schema. In order to expose a single graph, we are using a federation service, also in NestJS.

I was trying to integrate with '@graphql-eslint/eslint-plugin' and some strange exceptions were thrown:

> Unknown directive "@key"

Those errors were solved following a GitHub issue: https://github.com/cjoudrey/graphql-schema-linter/issues/210

I have created a new file with the type specifications according to the Apollo documentation: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/federation-spec/#federation-schema-specification

After solving this issue, I am getting few more errors that I have no idea what they mean and how to solve them:

> Parsing error: Cannot extend type "Query" because it is not defined. Did you mean "User"?

> Cannot extend type "Mutation" because it is not defined.

> Unknown type "Query". Did you mean "User"?

> Unknown type "Mutation".eslint

This is my schema:

```
extend type Query {
  users: [User]
  user(email: EmailAddress!): User
}

extend type Mutation {
  createUser(userData: UserData!): User
}

type User @key(fields: "email") {
  email: String!
  name: String
}

input UserData {
  email: String!
  name: String
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why I am getting those errors?

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, "Query" and "Mutation" are not defined.

It must first be defined before extending it, like so:

```
type Query {
  _empty: String
}

type Mutation {
  _empty: String
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added the definitions but now I am getting a different error: ``` Error: Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': You have used a rule which requires parserServices to be generated. You must therefore provide a value for the "parserOptions.project" property for @typescript-eslint/parser. ```